# Does the increased Blood Shard cap apply account wide?

Tags: diablo-iii

You can increase your Blood Shard cap by doing solo greater rifts. Is the increase to your cap applied account wide, seasonal, general or only character based?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Blood Shard cap is **per character type**, just like gold and paragon levels.

This means that normal, hardcore, seasonal, and seasonal hardcore characters all have separate blood shard caps.

I just tested this out.  Having not played since the patch, I had a cap of 500 on all of my normal and hardcore characters, and I created a couple level 1 seasonal characters for testing.  I ran and completed a Greater Rift 15 on my normal wizard, raising my cap to 650.  My normal Crusader also had the new cap of 650, but my hardcore Demon Hunter was still back at 500 along with both seasonal characters.