# How to increase blood shard cap

Tags: diablo-iii

I understand that there is a way to increase blood shard caps that involves Greater Rifts, based on this tooltip

[image: Blood Shards]

but how does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the increased Blood Shard cap apply account wide?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214495/does-the-increased-blood-shard-cap-apply-account-wide)

Comment: @dgw: that question doesn't cover increasing the cap

Comment: The answer to that question does.

Comment: Not to anyone searching for it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The maximum increases the base amount (500) by 10 for each level in your Greater Rift solo personal best.

For example, if your very first solo Rift run was set to level 20 and successful (within the time limit), your base maximum (500) would increase by 20*10, for a new maximum of 700. You don't have to finish the levels one by one--it only counts your personal best solo Rift success.